# Ionic Framework: Can't redirect to another page from my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Having trouble trying to get my app to switch to another page on a click in my controller. If anyone could give me  pointer on what I'm missing or doing wrong here it would really be appreciated!

here is my app.js
    .config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

```
    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'login': {
                    templateUrl : 'index.html',
                    controller: 'TestCrtl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('userprofile', {
            url: '/mainmenu',
            templateUrl: 'views/main-menu/main-menu.html'
        })          

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    })

    .controller('TestCtrl',function($scope, $location) {

    $scope.testMove = function($scope, $location) {
        console.log("Button was pressed!");
        $location.transitionTo('/mainmenu');
    }
});
```

and here is my index.html

```
<body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">


  <ion-view style="" title="MainMenu">
      <div class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
          <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
          <a class="button icon-right button-clear ion-gear-a"></a>
      </div>
      <ion-content style="background-color: #e9efec" class="has-header" scroll="true" padding="true">
          <div align="center" style="padding: 15%">
              <img style="height: 60px; width: 180px" src="img/digicellogo.png">
          </div>
          <div style="" class="list card">
              <div class="item item-body">
                  <form >
                      <label class="item item-input">
                          <a style="padding-right: 5px" href="">
                              <img style="height: 50px; width: 50px; " src="img/username-logo.JPG">
                          </a>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="DigicelID">
                      </label>
                      <label class="item item-input">
                          <a style="padding-right: 5px" href="">
                              <img style="height: 50px; width: 50px; " src="img/password-logo.JPG">
                          </a>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
                      </label>
                      <div align="right">
                      <button class="button button-clear button-assertive">
                          Forgot Password?
                      </button>
                      </div>
                     <a class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="testMove()"  ng-controller="TestCtrl">
                          Login
                      </a>
                      <button class="button button-block button-assertive">
                          Sign Up
                      </button>
                  </form>

                  </div>
              </div>
      </ion-content>


  </body>
```

EDIT:

My Updated controller in App.js:
No longer gives me a "undefined error" but simply does nothing? I don't know if I fully understand how to inject $scope.

```
 .controller('TestCtrl',['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.testMove = function() {
        console.log("Button was pressed!");
        $state.go('userprofile');
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$state.go('userprofile');`

instead of `location.transitionTo('/mainmenu');`

(remember to inject `$state` into your controller to test this)

Comment: Yep tried this. It got rid of the "undefined error", but just does nothing when pressed?

Comment: just to test, if you put "localhost.../mainmenu" in your browser when running ionic serve, does that load up the correct page?